# Using a JSON file to share data between python scripts running at the same time

Tags: python, json, selenium, flask

I'm a beginner programmer and have encountered this problem.

I wanted to make a script that receives webhooks from Tradingview (where some trading signals are generated) and then uses selenium to place trades on a trading website as fast as  possible.

I tried as hard as I could to put flask and selenium in the same script but that just wouldn't run (if you know how to do that it would bypass my problem).

So I came to the brilliant (not really) solution to  run 2 scripts at the same time where flask writes the new webhook info to a json file and my selenium bot loops infinitely and checks for changes to that json file, in which case it places the trades accordingly.

Now for the problem: when the json file is updated, the selenium bot stops and gives me this error (which I haven't found a good explanation to online):

```
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Right now I don't have the flask part figured out so i'm just using a python script on a timer to alter the json while my selenium bot runs. Hope you guys can help!

Comment: This is not a good approach in my opinion, you should use sockets to communicate between 2 processes

Comment: Forgive me for my  question but aren't sockets used to get streaming data from a service? I don't see how this would help communication between my 2 local scripts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sockets are used for communication between processes. Those processes *could* be your program and an external service, but they could also be two local programs.